# Require site visitors to refer others for premium access

Tags: e-commerce

Most ecommerce sites require customers to exchange their money for access to premium content. (Duh)

*Pay me money THEN you get access to my products.*

I have a website and want to require referals to my website for access to content.

*Bring 3 others to my website THEN you get access to my premium content.*

Any suggestions on how to achieve this or where to begin?

Comment: maybe i'm missing something, but could this be achieved simply by referral links?
some quick googling led me here:
https://dev.to/pieohpah/how-to-add-referral-links-to-your-signup-page-4ebe

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to share your thoughts. I thought of referral links, but I am only familiar of referral links for free content. I am aiming for something different. In order for a visitor to access my free content, I want to essentially put up a referral wall (as opposed to a paywall). I do not know a program or code that only allows visitors to access content when they have successfully referred 3 people. Or do standard referral links offer that? I am looking more into it :)